# Search json array for a specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets suppose I have a json array like this:

```
var data = {
    "cars": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Porsche",
            "number": "A00.0"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Audi",
            "number": "A00.1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I would like to check if my `var Carnumber = A00.1` is included in the `data['cars'].number` array.

I'm a beginner in programming and tried it like this:

```
$.map(data['cars'], function (field, i) {
    if(field.nummer == CarNumber){
        $('p').html(field.id);
    };
});
```

First problem is that it seems not to work: http://jsfiddle.net/wA9kj/

And second it would be interesting for me if the way I choose is really the fastest?
Thanks!

Comment: You have typo `field.nummer`! set it to `field.number`

Comment: As an aside, note that there is no JSON in your code. (JSON is a _string_ representation of data.)

Comment: Please remove the question, typo mistakes are not useful questions to keep around

Comment: By the way, why do you use `.map`? Should be `.each`...

Comment: map is the WRONG method to be using. You are not building a new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its `if(field.number == CarNumber){` not `if(field.nummer == CarNumber){`

Comment: Thanks i really didnt see it

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = Object.keys(data.cars).reduce(function (res,x) {
    return data.cars[x].number === 'A00.1' ? data.cars[x].id : res
}, 'object not found')

$('p').html(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var json_str = '{"cars":[{"id":2,"name":"Porsche","number":"A00.0"},{"id":3,"name":"Audi","number":"A00.1"}]}';
    var json_obj = JSON.parse(json_str);

    function search(query) {
        var result = '';
        console.log(json_obj.cars);
        for (var i = 0; i < json_obj.cars.length; i++) {
            if (json_obj.cars[i].number == query) {
                result = json_obj.cars[i].id;
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    var result = search('A00.1');

    alert(result); // returns 3

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.cars.length; i++) {
    if (data.cars[i].number == CarNumber) {
        $('p').html(data.cars[i].id);
        return;
    }
}
```